# Very weird entry in apache error_log. Is this an exploit fishing expedition?

Tags: apache, apache2, error-log

I was in the middle of tailing my error log for apache when this massive chunk came through. Never seen anything like it before. The IP maps out to RIPE Network Coordination Centere, with a PO box
link [here](https://www.whoisthisip.com/ipwhois/93.113.125.12)

Is this anything i should dig into further? I couldn't find much in regards to this when googling, other than RIPE is what appears to be an ISP.

`[Tue Mar 15 21:34:44.775251 2016] [core:error] [pid 22280] (36)File name too long: [client 93.113.125.12:44444] AH00036: access to /we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages failed (filesystem path '/var/www/html/we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages_we_are_looking_for_not_found_pages')`

Comment: Received the same today.
These connections are part of an Internet-wide research study being conducted by computer scientists at RWTH Aachen University. The research involves making benign connection attempts to every public IP address. By measuring the entire public address space, we are able to analyze global patterns and trends in protocol deployment and security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just received this request as well from the same IP. I don't see many others talking about it, so I guess it's new.

I assume it is a bot looking for insecure common management pages, and the actual request text is sort of a joke to the webmaster viewing the logs.

The script making these requests is doing exactly what the request URL says. It is sending requests to huge lists of IP addresses, IP address ranges, or even in some cases *every* IP address on the internet. It records whether or not the address returns with a status code - indicating that there is a web server running at that address.

It is unclear what's going to be done with this information. Maybe if they get a response they will put you on a list to be further probed. This is actually quite common.

These sorts of things are harmless unless you are using default passwords on some admin utility (wordpress, drupal, phpmyadmin, etc). If you start getting bombarded with these requests, you may want to employ the use of a more advanced hardware or software firewall, audit your publicly open ports, and maybe start restricting IP ranges.

http://who.is/whois-ip/ip-address/93.113.125.12

If this persists, you could always report the incident to the source's ISP.